# Tapestry JPA Jackson Deserialization

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson, tapestry

I'm working on a project I didn't initially create, in which the data was stored in-memory. I'm curently moving this data into the database. I'm doing this using hibernate and tapestry JPA. At some point in the project Jackson Deserialization is used (actually in connection with a UI, but I doubt that's relevant), via the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation, with a deserializer class (let's call it `DefinitionDeserializer`). `DefinitionDeserializer` then creates an instance of a POJO representation (let's call it `Definition`) of a database table (`D_DEFINITION`). However, `D_DEFINITION` has a connection to another table (`D_TYPE`) (and hence another POJO (`PeriodType`)). To resolve this connection, I'm using a tapestry service (`ConnectingService`), which I usually inject via the `@Inject` annotation. However, I can't use this method of injection when the object (in which I'm trying to inject the service, i.e. `DefinitionDeserializer`) was created via the `new` keyword - which seems to be the case for the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation. I also can't use `ConnectingService` without injecting it via the `@Inject` keyword, because then I couldn't inject any other services in `ConnectingService` either, which I'm currently doing.

I'm hoping this description didn't confuse you too much, I can't share the actual code with you and I don't think a minimal example would be much better, as it's quite a complicated case and wouldn't be such a small piece of code. If you need one, however, I can try to provide one.

Basically what I need is a way to tell `JsonDeserialize` to take a tapestry service instead of creating an instance of `DefinitionDeserializer` itself.

**Edit:** The classes as examples:

```
public DefinitionDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Definition> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //TODO: The injection doesn't work yet
    @Inject
    private ConnectingService connectingService;

    public DefinitionDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public DefinitionDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Definition deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Definition pd = new Definition();
        JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        if (node.has("type"))
            pd.setType(periodTypeDao.findByValue("PeriodType." + node.get("type").asText()));

        return pd;
    }

}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Definition.TABLE_NAME)
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE, region =
        JpaEntityModelConstants.CACHE_REGION_ADMINISTRATION)
public class Definition {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "D_DEFINITION";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 389511526676381027L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = JpaEntityModelConstants.SEQUENCE_NAME, sequenceName = JpaEntityModelConstants.SEQUENCE_NAME, initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = JpaEntityModelConstants.SEQUENCE_NAME)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "FK_TYPE", referencedColumnName = "ID")}
    )
    private PeriodType type;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public PeriodType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(PeriodType dpmType) {
        this.type = dpmType;
    }

    //More columns
}
```

---

`PeriodType` looks pretty much the same as `Definition`.

---

```
//BaseService contains all the standard methods for tapestry JPA services
public interface ConnectingService extends BaseService<PeriodType> {

}
```

---

```
public class ConnectingServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl<PeriodType> implements ConnectingService {

    public ConnectingServiceImpl() {
        super (PeriodType.class);
    }
}
```

---

Currently I'm using it like this (which doesn't work):

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = DefinitionDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = DefinitionSerializer.class)
private Definition definition;
```

Comment: A code example would definitely help.

Comment: @Christine I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@JsonDeserialize` doesn't create instances of deserialisers, it's just a hint for `ObjectMapper` to know which class to use when deserialising.

By default ObjectMapper uses `Class.newInstance()` for instantiating deserialisers, but you can specify custom `HandlerInstantiator` (`ObjectMapper#setHandlerInstantiator()`) in which you can use Tapestry's `ObjectLocator` to get instances of deserialisers, i.e. using `ObjectLocator#autobuild()`, or use `ObjectLocator#getService()` if your deserialisers are Tapestry services themselves.

Update:

```
public class MyHandlerInstantiator extends HandlerInstantiator
{
    private final ObjectLocator objectLocator;

    public MyHandlerInstantiator(ObjectLocator objectLocator)
    {
        this.objectLocator = objectLocator;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> deserializerInstance(
     DeserializationConfig config, Annotated annotated, Class<?> deserClass)
    {
        // If null returned here instance will be created via reflection
        // you can always use objectLocator, or use it conditionally
        // just for some classes
        return objectLocator.autobuild(deserClass);
    }

    // Other method overrides can return null
}
```

then later when you're configuring `ObjectMapper` use `@Inject`ed instance of `ObjectLocator` to create an instance of custom `HandlerInstantiator`, i.e.:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setHandlerInstantiator(new MyHandlerInstantiator(objectLocator));
return objectMapper;
```

Comment: That seems promising - could you provide a minimal example of how to specify the `HandlerInstantiator`? I currently don't know where to put `ObjectLocator#autobuild()`

Comment: Thanks for that. However, when I'm trying to use `ObjectLocator` via `@Inject`, I'm getting the exception: `No service implements the interface org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.ObjectLocator.`

Comment: I've noticed this behaviour if you try to `@Inject` it into page/component classes directly, but injections in services or builder/contribution methods in tapestry modules should work fine; you should also be able to `@Inject` services containing `ObjectLocator` to page/component classes without problems

Comment: But how do I do this then? Because currently I'm using the `ObjectMapper` inside a page

Comment: create a tapestry service like this:

    public class ObjectLocatorProvider
    {
        @Inject ObjectLocator objectLocator;

        public ObjectLocator getObjectLocator()
        {
            return objectLocator;
        }
    }

and inject it to your page